# Showing Ads GridView React Native

Tags: react-native, gridview, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I am working with **GridView** in which i have to show two items in GridLayout row count of 2 in **React-native IOS**.

The problem is that i have to show Ads after four items (i.e. 2 rows) that will cover width of mobile.But due to Span count the ads are also coming in Grid layout.Any help would be appreciated !!.

Want Output like this:-

[image]

I am using this react native library [GridView](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gridview) but not able to implement logic for random data to show one ad after 4 items using **DataSource**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Snack for the same created from the example given by the author in GitHub. It is doing what exactly you asked for.
A while loop can be used in _createRandomData function to splitting the layout and putting ad in between.

[Snack Preview](https://snack.expo.io/@sarabs3/grid-try)

[image]